# ReportView - Registros por página

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Tenho um `DataSet` populado com dois registros e gostaria de imprimir o primeiro registro em uma página, o próximo em uma nova página, e assim por diante.

Essa situação é necessária para impressão de crachás em um SP35Plus.

Comment: Vê se isso te ajuda http://paulohdsousa.blogspot.com.br/2012/01/relatorios-com-reportviewer-e-linq-c.html http://paulohdsousa.blogspot.com.br/2012/01/relatorios-com-reportviewer-c.html